# Cancel data insert inside beforeInsert event if it already exists in table

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

There is a need to insert multiple rows in a table. I am using `TypeOrm` which has `.save()` method.

`.save()` method is used to insert data in bulk, and it checks for the inserting primary key ID. If they exist it updates, otherwise inserts.

I want to do the checking on some other field `shortLInk`. Which is not possible with `.save()`

So I tried to do inside `beforeInsert()` event, things are fine but I need to cancel the isnertions if row is find.

*Is there any way to achieve it?* I couldn't find anything in documentation.

I can throw an error inside `beforeInsert()` but it will cancel whole insertions.

---

```
  async shortLinks(links: Array<string>): Promise<Array<QuickLinkDto>> {
    const quickLinks: Array<QuickLinkDto> = links.map((link) => ({
      actualLink: link,
    }));
    return this.quickLinkRepository.save(quickLinks, {});
  }
```

```
@Injectable()
export class QuickLinkSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<QuickLink>
{
  constructor(
    datasource: DataSource,
    @InjectRepository(QuickLink)
    private readonly quickLinkRepository: Repository<QuickLink>,
  ) {
    datasource.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  listenTo() {
    return QuickLink;
  }

  async beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<QuickLink>) {
    const shortLink = await getShortLink(event.entity.actualLink);

    const linkExists = await this.quickLinkRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        shortLink,
      },
    });

    if (linkExists) {
      // Discard the insertion if the row already exists
      return delete event.entity; // throws error
    }
    event.entity.shortLink = shortLink;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a transaction, all the operations are atomic, meaning either all of them are executed or none of them are. you can check for the existence of the `shortLink` before the insert and if it exists, you can cancel the whole transaction.

```
async shortLinks(links: Array<string>): Promise<Array<QuickLinkDto>> {
  const quickLinks: Array<QuickLinkDto> = links.map((link) => ({
    actualLink: link,
  }));

  const queryRunner = this.quickLinkRepository.manager.connection.createQueryRunner();

  try {
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    const result = await this.quickLinkRepository.save(quickLinks, {});

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();

    throw error;
  } finally {
    await queryRunner.release();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class QuickLinkSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<QuickLink>
{
  constructor(
    datasource: DataSource,
    @InjectRepository(QuickLink)
    private readonly quickLinkRepository: Repository<QuickLink>,
  ) {
    datasource.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  listenTo() {
    return QuickLink;
  }

  async beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<QuickLink>) {
    const shortLink = await getShortLink(event.entity.actualLink);

    const linkExists = await this.quickLinkRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        shortLink,
      },
    });

    if (linkExists) {
      // Discard the insertion if the row already exists
      throw new Error('The short link already exists');
    }
    event.entity.shortLink = shortLink;
  }
}
```